# Google-Fu chat room frozen

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-declined, chat

This is the first time I've seen the Google-Fu chat room frozen:
[image]

Can't we keep the Google-Fu chat room permanently active?

If not, I want it to be.

I'm in this chat room, if you want to chat: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13056/spreadsheet-nerds

**== edit ==**
Did the rules change or did somebody listen:
[image]

Comment: Added [meta-tag:status-declined] because it's well known that this will not be changed any time soon (was requested in Meta SE since 2010).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is ludicrous that [Google-Fu](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7/google-fu) is subject to being frozen. There is advice all over the place for some matters to "take it to chat" and yet 93,441 users here may not be able to.

At the very least the Help Center might caution "but don't bother to try to if there has been no eligible activity there for two weeks".

Answer (score 3):

You just need to have at least two different users talking in a room and to not leave a room empty (empty based on messages, not users logged in) for two weeks in order to keep it alive.

It is a minimal requirement really, so just pop in every now and then (but within 14 days) and it should stay open.

Comment: Yeah I know that.

Comment: So if it can't sustain one message every 14 days between two users, the room doesn't need to exist

Comment: So, your answer is: _No, that's not possible_? In our help (http://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/chat) we refer to the chat possibility. Two chat rooms appear and one of them is frozen !! That's the way to build a community. BTW, I've retagged the question to contain the feature-request tag.

Comment: @JacobJanTuinstra the way to build a community is to have chat active with people.. having it permanently open with no activity isn't going to do anything

Comment: @Sathya I disagree with you on that.

Comment: Not a no. But a "If we want to be open, we need to be talking."