# OMG Google-Fu is gone?

Tags: support, chat

I'm at a total loss. Despite the [apparent](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2672/google-fu-chat-room-frozen) longer grace period, we let our chat room slip through our hands.

### @moderator team:

Please re-enstate the Web Applications chat room !!

Let's make the chat room great again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The chatroom has been unfrozen and reinstated.

Comment: Yes.  If there's no activity for 2 (or 3, maybe) weeks, they freeze.  It takes 2 seconds to unfreeze, so if it does, just let someone know.